# How can I let user see Window with delay in SwiftUI for macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want my app in SwiftUI for macOS get shown or available to user with some sec delay like 5 sec delay, how can I do this? Just given more info, **I want nothing shown to user in 5 sec**, and after that Window get available to user. Also I know the use case of timer or DispatchQueue, but I have no idea how can I use them for making this delay.

```
    @main
struct test58App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            // Here, I want Window get shown to user with some delay like 5 sec delay!
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show something, it can be the color black but something research splash screen there are many ways to approach

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, i said "I want nothing shown to user in 5 sec"

Comment: No misunderstanding. It isn’t possible to do what you want to do. You can’t pause the startup code.

Comment: I did not asked the opinion about UI or what would be user possibly thinks, those points are not related to my question. So I think there is a misunderstanding in between but it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a possible approach:

```
@main
struct test2App: App {
    @State private var visible: Bool = false
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Group {
                if visible {
                    ContentView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    visible = true
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I clearly said in question that "I want nothing shown to user in 5 sec"

Comment: Maybe change your question title to "Window" and not "ContentView". I think this caused the misunderstandings

Comment: I can do that, thanks for advise.

Answer (score 0):

## Approach

- The root view (`ContentView`) needs to be shown, the app can't be without the root view
- Keep the ContentView empty till 5 seconds, then show what ever you want to show

## My opinion

- It is not a good idea to keep the root view totally empty, at least show a spinner or some text otherwise user might think the app is not responding  / too slow and kill the app

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isReady = false
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isReady {
                Text("Ready")
            } else {
//                Text("Not Ready")
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5_000_000_000)
            isReady = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I clearly said in question that "I want nothing shown to user in 5 sec"

Comment: @macCoder2022 Just curious why do you want no window to be shown for 5 seconds?

Comment: I want lunch NSView from a SwiftUI View for more control on Windows and Views, in the fact I am not looking for 5 sec delay it would be like 0.3-0.5 sec delay

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the whole window, this would work. But it can be, that the window is visible very shortly...

```
@main
struct test2App: App {
    
    init() {
        NSApplication.shared.hide(nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            NSApplication.shared.unhide(nil)
            NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me at all, but thanks

Comment: Interesting. Did you see an error, or did just nothing happen? Is the init function being called?

Comment: It simply load the app as normal, no change at all

Comment: Is the init function being called?